# Retornar script JavaScript com Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Usando o Node.JS quero ler um script JavaScript em uma pasta e retornar ele.
Acontece que quando eu acesso o arquivo pelo navegador, o código aparece normalmente.
Porém o script não é incorporado na página HTML usando a tag `<script>`

Estou usado a framework Express. Tentei fazer desta forma porém não funcionou.

```
app.get(/\/.+/, function(req, res){
    var file = __dirname + "/www/public" + req.path;

    if(fs.existsSync(file)){
        if(file.match(/\.js$/)){
            res.header("Content-Type", "application/javascript");
        }

        res.sendFile(file);
        res.status(200);
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/www/404.html");
        res.status(404);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

precisa mapear os arquivos estáticos com isso você vai poder usar em suas
paginas os arquivos (css,js,etc..)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


//Middlewares
app.use(express.static('./app/public')); // mapeando arquivos estaticos com express

app.use(express.static('./node_modules'))

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Isso funcionou, porém o JavaScript continua sem ser incorporado à página HTML. Abro ele no link direto, mas na página é como se a tag `<script>` sequer existisse. Nem erro aparece. Detalhe que arquivo CSS está funcionando corretamente, o problema é só com .js

Comment: ta usando ejs ou pug ?

Comment: Já que não sei do que se trata, acho que nenhum dos dois.

Comment: Meu deus, me desculpa por fazer perder seu tempo... Eu uso NoScript, e não habilitei o localhost para executar código. ¬¬'  
Agradeço por me mostrar essa maneira mais prática de poder dar acesso a arquivos de uma pasta.